# How to discribe the complement of a Seifert surface

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

We can construct a covering space of a knot complement by cutting along a Seifert surface and glue several copies together. So I want to know how the complement of a Seifert surface looks like.

What I can only say is that the boundary of this space is a surface obtained by gluing two copies of the Seifert surface along their boundary.

For the unknot, I can easily imagine after cutting along a disk in $S^3$, we get a 3-ball because a 3-ball ($D^2\times I$) in $S^3$ is removed. How about more non-trivial examples? How about trifoil?

Comment: The trefoil knot is a fibered knot -- if you take the complement of the genus-1 Seifert surface $\Sigma$ you get something homeomorphic to $\Sigma\times [0,1]$. The figure-eight knot is also fibered, and you get the same space as for the trefoil knot. The knot complements here are distinguished by how the two sides of this thickened surface are glued back together.

Comment: @KyleMiller Thank you! One more question, is every Seifert surface of the trefoil a fiber of some fibration over $S^1$? How about non-fibered knots?

Comment: No, but every minimal-genus Seifert surface of the trefoil is isotopic to one another. For non-fibered knots, there's not going to be such a nice description; maybe you could choose one, come up with a Seifert surface, and maybe use surgery to see the complement in another form?